# Trial version for a Mac App - considerations and issues

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, app-store, trial

We've recently launched our app, which is being sold via the App Store and on our website.

The thing is we also need to create a trial version.

**On the conceptual side**, what should be limited in the trial version (given that the app is a multi-purpose code editor):

- Limited-time usage?
- Restricted functionality? Which one?

**As for the practical side of things:**

- Are there any Cocoa frameworks that help with creating a "trial" version?
- Is there any risk (and what should we do about it) that a trial version may be "updateable" via the App Store, as if it has been purchased normally?

Any ideas/input are more than welcome, especially if you've done it before!

---

**P.S.** *I know this one may seem as an "opinion-based" question (and I wouldn't mind if you shared yours, to be honest). However, it isn't. What I'm looking for is pointers/examples  of similar attempts or a Cocoa-friendly approach.*

Comment: I don't see a programming question, so why ask this here?  Perhaps http://apple.stackexchange.com is better, or maybe Apple's developer forums.

Comment: @trojanfoe I thought of posting on apple.stackexchange.com, however I still consider it a code-related question. Pretty much as if I needed something related to the Sparkle framework (for updates), I'd still post here. (As for the post being favourited, one of them is mine - as I usually do for posts I need to be watching closely :-) )

Comment: The question relates to design, not programming.

Comment: @trojanfoe I don't know - if a moderator finds it more suitable in another stackexchange site, that'd be fine. However, on the programming side, I'd still need to know if there is already a Cocoa solution for that. (I have searched everywhere but found nothing...)

Comment: Linking to your app in the first sentence feels a bit spammy. For the purpose of answering your question, a link is probably not necessary.

Comment: @mattt Not my intention at all. Thanks for pointing it out! ;-)